# Can a restriction of a forgetful functor actually be a left adjoint?

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

Let $G$ be a group, $X$ a set, and let $U$ be the forgetful functor $\mathtt{Grp\to Set}$. Then, if we have an inclusion (or any injection) $UG\hookrightarrow X$, we have an induced inclusion (or monomorphism) $G\hookrightarrow \mathfrak S(X)$, the group of bijections over $X$. Can we interpret this as some kind of adjunction?

The unit of such an adjunction would be Cayley’s theorem, but what about its counit? Can we naturally get from the set of bijections over $X$ to $X$? I’m pretty sure the answer is no, but I might miss something.

Furthermore, there’s no way $U$ is actually a left adjoint as it is clearly not cocontinuous, but what about its restriction to some well-chosen subcategory? Can we promote it to a left adjoint one way or another? If not, what does the existence of an induced mono $G\hookrightarrow \mathfrak S(X)$ for every mono $UG\hookrightarrow X$ tell us ?

Comment: What is the induced inclusion $G \hookrightarrow \mathfrak S(X)$?  Something like left multiplication on $UG \subset X$, and the identity on $X \setminus UG$?

Comment: In essence, that’s what I was thinking about: the example I had in mind was with $G=\mathfrak S(2)$ and $X=\{0,1,2\}$.